# Connect to a remote database...online database

Tags: android

I've been looking for a week now... I need some help connecting to a remote database... I want my app to get data out of the database and update the database...
I've tried [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) but i don't understand it.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest way to connect  a Mobile (ANDROID, iPhone, Symbian, WP7, you name it) device to a Data Base is to write a HTTP based proxy for your database.

This is:

```
ANDROID -> HTTP -> APPLICATION SERVER -> DATABASE
```

And then the other way around to get results:

```
DATABASE -> APPLICATION SERVER -> HTTP -> ANDROID
```

In this scenario, you will write a HTTP based application in your favorite language (PHP, Python, Perl, Java, .NET) and deploy it in your favorite Application Server (Apache, Tomcat, IIS) and, in that application you will publish URLs your Android app will access to send/retrieve data to your database.

Comment: is it possible to give me an example plz

Comment: i understand what your saying...im new to programming...so i need a example of how to do this...

Comment: does any one have a sample program that i can have a look at please?

Comment: @sakkie. do you know how to write a WebServer APP that will get data from a DataBase?

Comment: @pablo. no i dont know. can you help me plz

Comment: @sakkie: OK. Start by learning how to do a very simple WebServer APP. Pick a language. There are plenty of tutorials on the NET.

Comment: @pablo...i tried this...but got nowhere...im really new to programming...so if you cant help me with sample app then i guess i might give up even before i really started...

Comment: @sakkie never just give up.  Sample apps are great, but they're not the be all end all.  I'm new to android programming as well and it's a big learning process.  When I learned php I had to sit down with a book (learn php in 24 hours) and read and go through the entire book to understand.  There are a lot of tutorials to show you have to use php to access a database.  You'll have to learn the basics before a sample script would be any use to you.  Take a weekend and go through a book on php (or another language, I just like php myself).

Answer (score 3):

I think rather than connect to a database remotely, you want to use REST services to get and post data to your remote database.

You can create a REST service to wrap your remote database query and return via http, JSON (which I prefer) or XML.

In your android app you can do an http get or post to consume the aforementioned service

Answer (score 3):

1. Create the database in the server
2. Write server side program to store and retrieve data
3. write the android program to access the data using HttpPost class

All the best...